# Using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have worked with this project for a while where I am using unique pointers, but I find myself unsure about if I am using them correctly.

My biggest doubt is when using these unique pointers inside of constructors or methods, here are some examples:

I have this Event class, which take unique_ptr's of simulation, train, trainstation and time objects:

```
class Event {
public:
    Event(unique_ptr<Simulation> simulation, unique_ptr<Train> train, unique_ptr<TrainStation> station, unique_ptr<Time> t)
        : sim(move(simulation)), tåg(move(train)), tStation(move(station)), time(move(t)) {};

    virtual ~Event() {};


    virtual void processEvent() = 0;


    unique_ptr<Time> getTime() const {
        return time;
    }

    void printEvent();

protected:
    unique_ptr<Simulation> sim;
    unique_ptr<Train> tåg;
    unique_ptr<TrainStation> tStation;
    unique_ptr<Time> time;
};
```

The Event class has multiple subclasses, here is an example of one of them:

```
class AssembleEvent : public Event
{
public:
    AssembleEvent(unique_ptr<Simulation> simulation, unique_ptr<Train> train, unique_ptr<TrainStation> station, unique_ptr<Time> time) 
        : Event(move(simulation), move(train), move(station), move(time)) {};
    virtual ~AssembleEvent() {};

    virtual void processEvent();
};
```

So my question here is, am I using the unique_ptr's in a correct way? Is this the way to use unique_ptr's or is there another way to do this?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: My question for you is are you sure you even need a pointer type here?

Comment: `unique_ptr<Time> getTime() const` should not compile as shown.

Comment: @NathanOliver It makes sense for me to use a pointer, because I have made these objects as unique pointers in another class, and I want to use the exact same objects here. For example I have the printEvent() method, where I want to print out the time, the train number and so on on the screen to the user, and I need these objects to access this information..

Comment: @manni66 Could you please explain to me why it should not compile? :-)

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @manni66 At the moment there are many errors in the program so it's a bit difficult to see the problem with this only :-) .. but there is a red line under time, so I suppose it wouldn't work.. I am not sure how I can make it work though, I have this smart pointer to a time object as a member, and I want to make it possible to get this time object, I am not sure how to accomplish this though.

Comment: To be honest this code looks overcomplicated. It seems that you are using pointers for every little thing just because you can. One wants to keep ownership structure as simple as possible. In the best situation you can create objects directly and pass them around by reference ensuring that they will survive for long enough, only when things get more twisted you may need to start manually allocating them on the heap and transferring ownership using `unique_ptr`, andfinally at the worst-case scenario you may need to share ownership between multiple entities using `shared_ptr` or even `weak_ptr`.

Comment: You can't make it possible as unique_ptr! unique_ptr is about ownership: you would give your time object away.